# Which Universities in US should I apply to study for a Masters in Statistics?

Tags: soft-question, education

I've decided that I want to join a masters programme that prepares graduates for industry work as opposed for a phd. At the same time, I also want to really understand the theory behind the statistical methods that I will be learning. I'm interested in machine mearning and time series analysis.

EDIT:

Given my interests, maybe a Masters in Statistics isn't the right choice i.e. perhaps I should consider Masters in Analytics, Operations Research, etc. I'm open to other suggestions too.